# Is there a way to organize the files in actual directories in a cmake generated visual studio project in folders?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, directory-structure

Im trying to generate a visual studio project using cmake in which the source files should be organized in their physical folders just as they originally were when clicking "Show All Files" option in visual studio solution explorer ? I've tried something but I could only organize them in visual studio filters.

This is the cmake code I have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Turbo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "src/*.cpp" "src/*.h")

add_library(Turbo SHARED ${SOURCES})

set_target_properties(Turbo PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

target_compile_definitions(Turbo PRIVATE TURBO_WINDOWS TURBO_EXPORT)

source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src FILES ${SOURCES})
```